# Kafka Consumer Hung on Certain Partitions - Single Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In my test environment, I  have three Kafka brokers and my topic is having 16 partitions, there are 16 IOT Devices which post the messages to Kafka. I have a single system with one Kafka Consumer which subscribes to this topic. Each IOT devices post the message to Kafka every second and its distributed uniformly. I am
 printing the offset and partition to which the data posted using Kafka Producer Call back method on these each IOT device . My consumer stops consuming the messages from certain partitions randomly and at the same time its processing records from other partitions. I actually verified the IOT device logs and I could see that the data is actually getting posted to the particular partitions where the consumer has stopped consuming and I am able to see the offsets getting incremented for those partitions. There are no exceptions or any error of any kind in the consumer except that I don't see any processing logs for the partitions which stopped processing. Below I have captured the snipped of my consumer code .

```
public class MyKafkaConumer extends Thread {

   private static final AtomicBoolean running= new AtomicBoolean(true); 
   private static final KafkaConsumer consumer;
   public static final MyKafkaConumer INSTANCE = new MyKafkaConumer();

   static {

          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafkaServer101:9092,kafkaServer102:9092,kafkaServer103:9092");
          props.put("group.id", "mykafa-group");
          props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
          props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");      
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                  StringDeserializer.class.getName());
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                  IOTDeserializer.class.getName());
          consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props);
          consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("mytopic"));

       }

     private MyKafkaConumer() {
          super("MyKafkaConumer");
    }

   public void run() {


       try {
        while (running.get()) {
            ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(2000L);
            records.forEach(record -> {
                System.out.printf("Consumer Record:(%s, %s, %d, %d)\n", record.key(), record.value(),
                        record.partition(), record.offset());
            });

        } 
    } finally {
          consumer.close();
    }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       MyKafkaConumer.INSTANCE.start();
       MyKafkaConumer.INSTANCE.join();
}
}
```

I only have a single Consumer with a single thread running . What could be the reason for the Kafka Consumer to stop processing from certain paritions while the processing is happening for other paritions even though the producer is sending message to the partitions where it was stuck ? Any help here is very much appreciated. The partitions are getting recovered after some random time intervals, but its not useful since the application lost real time data.  I am using Kafka version 0.11.01 version for both Kafka broker and client

Comment: it stops randomly, but later after some time is it picking up again? @user

Comment: If I restart the consumer It picks up immediately from the latest offset

Comment: what about if you don't restart, i'm i would like to know are you missing data from that partition after it stops consuming from that partition? or its getting recover after some time intervals ? @user

Comment: I just checked lat 3 hours logs , it hasn't recovered. It  starts consuming only after restart

Comment: I  was wrong yesterday, the partitions are getting recovered after some time intervals

Comment: I am new to Kafka and facing the issue. Any thoughts?